# How to hide a txt file at the time of its creation?

Tags: file, batch-file, hide

Please is there anyway in batch, by attributes of files, to hide (not visible into the explorer) a .txt file at the time of its creation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If Explorer has 'show system and hidden files' enabled then you will see all files in Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read `HELP ATTRIB` and then try

```
ECHO Hello >hello.txt
ATTRIB +H hello.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo   > c:\test\myFile.txt
attrib +h c:\test\myFile.txt
```

you can echo (alt+0160) to make a blank-looking file

Comment: That's false! This will create a file with 3 bytes: hex `A0 0D 0A`. To create a empty file you can `COPY NUL file`. But hide part is correct.

Comment: I said blank-looking! Not the same as empty unfortunately